# Excel Addins and Extra Drivers

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, visual-foxpro

I've built an Excel that uses an ODBC driver (yeah, dumb) to query a FoxPro database (because my company lives in the stone ages). I'm going to roll out this program as an Addin.

Unfortunately, to use VFP with ODBC, you need the VFPODBC.dll. Rolling this out within the company means I need unique paperwork on every machine that I want to deploy. My question is: If I roll out my program as an Addin, will the code reference to the Addin file make it so I do not need to roll out the drivers?

My understanding would be that, either a server running the Addin could hold the drivers and do all the calculations, spitting only results back to the User's Excel. Or, deploying the Addin will just create a local version, putting the demand on the User's system.

If it's the former solution, I should have no problem with the .dll files (but I risk some hearty performance issues). If it's the latter, I have to roll out all necessary drivers with the program, right?

Comment: Yes - that's about it.

Comment: But which is it? Or is there a way to configure it to either scenario?

Comment: If you want users to be able to run your queries from their own PC then they will need the required drivers installed. If you want to run the queries on a central server then that's going to be more complex - you'd have to set up a "query service" to run the queries and return the results: I don't think you'd be able to run your add-in as-is on a server.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you rewrite it using VFP OLEDB/ADO and just install that on each PC. Alternatively rewrite it as a COM server using VFP if you want it to run on a central server and be connected to from Excel/VBA on multiple PCS. That isn't a project for the fainthearted however.